# Dozer Object Mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, dozer

```
I have following classes

// source clasess

Class A
{
    private List<Info> infoList;
    private String parent_Id;
},

Class Info
{
   private String child_name;
   private String child_Id;
}

// destination classes

Class B
{
    private List<Data> dataList;
}

 Class Data
 {
    private String data_parent_id;
    private String data_child_id;
    private String data_name;
 }
```

Now how to map class A to Class B . I have tried with the following mapping configuration but I am not sure how to refer parent_id from child object.

```
    mapping between A to B : 

    dataList:infoList

    mapping for Info to Data object :

     data_name:child_name,
     data_child_id:child_id,
```

Now I am asking how to map data_parent_id to #A.parent_id .

```
     i.e data_parent_id:#A.parent_id
```

All the classes are from third party sources I can't change the structure of it.

Comment: Good to refer: https://howtodoinjava.com/automation/dozer-bean-mapping-examples/ , https://www.baeldung.com/dozer

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have already read those blogs but I couldn't find what I am looking for

Comment: Are you asking how to map all of the data_parent_id values to the single A.parent_id field? If I understand that correctly, it requires some additional logic beyond a simple object mapping to determine what to do for each different data_parent_id. Can you expand the scope of your question to include the additional logic and mapping goal for each time the data_parent_id changes?